# Maximum Theorem with concavity condition

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I read on Wikipedia's entry for the [Maximum Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem#Variants) that:

> If $f$ is concave and $C$ has a convex graph, then $f^*$ is concave and $C^*$ is convex-valued.

I'm working on the first part right now (showing $f^*$ is convex).

I started out writing
$$f^*(t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2)=\max\nolimits_x\{f(x,(t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2):x\in \Gamma(t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2)\},$$
and by concavity of $f$, 
$$f^*(t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2)\geq \max\nolimits_x\{tf(x,\theta_1)+(1-t)f(x,\theta_2):x\in \Gamma(t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2)\},$$
but I'm not sure what to do next, because if I simply split the max into two separate parts, I think the inequality sign should go the other direction. And how should I deal with the $\Gamma(t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2)$?

Thanks in advance to any help!

Okay, just in case anyone is interested...I found the answer in Sundaram's First Course in Optimization, pp239:

Take $\theta_1$ and $ \theta_2 $, and let $\theta'$=$t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2$.
Pick $x_1 \in \Gamma^*(\theta_1), x_2 \in \Gamma^*(\theta_2)$ (so x's are the maximizers given the $\theta$'s), and let $x'=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$. Denote $f^*(\theta)$ to be the maximum that could be achieved given parameter $\theta$. Now we have:

$f^*(\theta')\geq f(x',\theta')=f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2,t\theta_1+(1-t)\theta_2)\geq tf(x_1,\theta_1)+(1-t)f(x_2,\theta_2)=tf^*(\theta_1)+(1-t)f^*(\theta_2)$.